# COM interface declaration and use (or lack thereof)

Tags: c#, c++, interface, com, com-interop

As I understand it, COM interfaces are abstract classes in C++ but for some reason translate to C# interfaces. Why must one declare all methods of an interface in C#, even when one does not intend to use any of its members? Take for example [IFileOperation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775771(v=vs.85).aspx), I've tried removing function declarations which I have verified are never called in my code but it results in System.AccessViolationException being thrown.

Comment: When you're the caller (like with IFileOperation), you must specify the same number/layout of methods, but you don't have to define all methods with details if you don't use it. Plus if the only method you use is the 3rd, say, then you can just define method1(), method2() w/o args (as placeholders) and then the real method3 with the exact same signature. But when someone's calling you (like when you implement IFileOperationProgressSink ), then you must define all methods with all signatures. Interfaces are just binary contracts.

Comment: The 3rd in what order, alphabetical?

Comment: Nope, names are just for humans. In the end, an interface is just a table of pointers to methods. Remember: it's all binary, not like .NET with namespaces or classes names, etc.

Comment: Can I find these tables on MSDN or do I have to dig deeper?

Comment: They're defined in an  .idl and/or in a .h from the Windows SDK. For example: IFileOperation is in C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.15063.0\um\ShObjIdl_core.h on my PC. The table is the list of methods (and base interface methods, including IUnknown ones). Don't trust MSDN for that, order of methods is not meaningul, it's just for documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code doesn't run in isolation. A COM interface is a binary contract between code offering a service, and code using those services. The contract is an all-or-nothing agreement (with the caveat that E_NOTIMPL can be used to indicate certain optional methods are not available, *if the interface documentation indicates that this is allowed*).

`IFileOperation` is not your contract. It belongs to Microsoft. It's used to interact with Microsoft code and other 3rd party code. That code (which you don't own) expects classes implementing the interface to provide a function pointer for each method in the interface (and put it in a VTable). That's what the interface means. You don't get to not provide that function pointer. And that code *will call* any method in the interface it sees fit to call, according to the documented rules of the interface. It's not your choice.

If you are absolutely sure the method is not called it means you're not using it to interact with the shell. If you don't like some of the methods and you don't interact with the shell (or other 3rd party code) you can always make up your own interface; nobody forces you to borrow someone else's. Make sure both the COM server and Client agree on the interface definition.

On the other hand, if you are interacting with the shell, you don't know which methods the shell will call on you. You have to provide implementations for all of them, even if all you do is return an error. I'm not super-familiar with `IFileOperation` so read the documentation carefully. It's possible that some methods can return specific error messages (like E_NOTIMPL) to indicate the specific functionality is not available.

The fact that you are getting an invalid access violation strongly suggests one of those methods you dislike is indeed being called.

Comment: It's not that I "dislike" them, it's just that I feel like it's extra work to write them out manually, as I do it, when I personally won't be calling some of them. I did remove all the functions of IShellItem and it still works. I guess it just depends on the interface in question.

Comment: I'm still a bit unclear on what you were doing. Note that copying an interface from the documentation and calling it IFileOperation does not make it *the* `IFileOperation`. Interface names are arbitrary and for the benefit of the developer. The real name of the IFileOperation in your documentation link is `IID {947AAB5F-0A5C-4C13-B4D6-4BF7836FC9F8}`. If you make a new interface with a similar layout and you call it IFileOperation, fine - but your interface is whatever IID you assign to it in the IDL - and then you just need to make sure *both sides* know to use that one, not IID {947...9F8}.

Comment: I declared the two interfaces and linked them with their respective GUIDs. I'm able to use IFileOperation and IShellItem to delete things but I just realised that if I removed the functions from my declaration of IFileOperations, the ones I'm not calling, then the program crashes but if I do the same to IShellItem, it works just fine.

Comment: I see. Don't delete anything from the existing interfaces; even if they "work" today, it might blow up at the next Windows patch, or on older versions of Windows, or future ones, or when you install another shell utility, or on someone else's machine, or when you do something on Explorer you haven't tried yet, or when running Word... If a method is missing from the VTable, the shell will eventually be jumping to random memory. If you absolutely don't have the time to investigate the interface contract more fully, implement methods that returns E_NOIMPL; at least you won't risk hard-crashing.